# Docker - Getting manifest for openjdk:8-java-alpine not found

Tags: docker

I tried small docker application.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-java-alpine
ADD target/hello-world-rest-api.jar hello-world-rest-api.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-c","java -jar /hello-world-rest-api.jar
```

Getting the below error when I tried to run build cmd.

```
C:\Docker-SpringBoot-Projects\docker-crash-course-master\01-hello-world-rest-api>docker build -t dowlathbasha/hello-world-rest-api:dockerfile1 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  16.97MB
Step 1/3 : FROM openjdk:8-java-alpine
manifest for openjdk:8-java-alpine not found
```

Pls, suggest.

Comment: openjdk:8-java-alpine is not there in docker hub. try openjdk:8-alpine

Answer (score 2):

There is no image named, `openjdk:8-alpine` hosted in [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/search?q=openjdk%3A8-java-alpine&type=image)

Try using alternative image such as `FROM openjdk:8-alpine` in Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

you may use following docker image for java8

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk8:x86_64-alpine-jre8u232-b09
RUN mkdir /app
COPY ./target/hello-world-rest-api.jar /app/hello-world-rest-api.jar
WORKDIR /app
CMD ["java", "-jar", "hello-world-rest-api.jar"]
```

source:- https://hub.docker.com/r/adoptopenjdk/openjdk8